# are there any differences between symmetric and symmetrical?

Tags: vocabulary, comparison

I looked up the free dictionary, under symmetric it said another word for symmetrical. But which one is more common? Any other possible distinctions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible distinction I can think of.

- *symmetric* applies in particular to **relations**: A is to B as B is to A, A does C to B and B does C to A, and so on. There is some kind of symmetric relation between A and B.
- *symmetrical* applies in particular to **objects**: a circle is symmetrical radially, that's a symmetrical vase.

(Note: *possible distinction*. This does not mean that you cannot use either here - you can.)

Well, that's what occurs to me. However, this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=symmetric+relation%2C+symmetrical+relation&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csymmetric%20relation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csymmetrical%20relation%3B%2Cc0) suggests that the first bullet is no longer so relevant as it once was.

[This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=symmetric+object%2Csymmetrical+object&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csymmetric%20object%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csymmetrical%20object%3B%2Cc0) does support the second bullet somewhat.

Comment: I think you messed it up the order of symmetric and symmetrical. Can you look at your answer again plz? I'm not sure if you made a mistake or not

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Are you asking whether I really meant to swap *symmetric* and *symmetrical* in the two bullet descriptions, so that, for example, *symmetrical* is especially about relations and *symmetric* is especially about objects?  If so, then no; I meant what is written.

Answer (score -1):

No much difference. [WordWebOnline](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/SYMMETRIC) suggests 'symmetrical' as a synonym or a variant of 'symmetric'.

> symmetric  - Having similarity in size, shape, and relative position of corresponding parts

Answer (score -1):

*symmetric* seems to be primarily used in math contexts.

*symmetrical* is the adjective form of the noun *symmetry*.

To say more requires more context in your question.